# How to share cache memory in Java Multithreading?

Tags: java, memory

I am running multiple threads in Java.

I read a large file that is about 5 GB and share this file among multiple threads.

So I read the file and then call multiple threads.

As far as I know, Java threads reads a shared variable and stores it in its own cache.

So for my case, if I have 5 threads, the program will take upto 25 GB memory.

However, I want my threads not to store a shared variable in its own cache, but to share it without storing it.

Is there a way to do so?

thanks in advance.

Comment: The variable that gets cached isn't the whole object, just the reference to it. The CPU may also cache parts of the 5G, but not the whole thing. You generally don't need to worry about that level of the CPU's operation.

Answer (score 0):

The threads should have only the reference to the data.
all Java objects are passed by reference. the reference is passed by value.

If you want, you can use Singleton to hold the data and to be a cache:

```
   public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;

   private byte[] yourData;
   private ClassicSingleton() {} 
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         synchronized(SingletonTest.class) {
         if(instance == null) 
           instance = new ClassicSingleton();    
     }
      return instance;
   }

   public byte[] getYourData(){
      return this.yourdata;
   }

}
```

In the threads you can call your data like this:

```
ClassicSingleton.getInstance().getYourData();
```

Comment: The `instance` field _must_ be volatile for this to be correct. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java